# Magento : Get Quantity of Added Product in cart_product_add_after Event

Tags: product, event-observer, magento-1, addtocart, qty

I need to get quantity of product being added NOT quantity of that product in cart.

E.g. I am on product view page and set quantity to 5 and click on "Add to Cart". I need to get that quantity in observer.

How can I do that?

Currently I have this, but it gets quantity of that product in cart. E.g. if I already had 3 of same products in cart and I added 5 more of same product then $qty will be 8 not 5. That is not what I need.

```
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
$qty = $product->getQty();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do `var_dump($product->getData()` you will see that there is a field with name `qty_to_add` in the data. This field contains the quantity which was requested to be add.
So to get what you want use below code.

```
$product->getQtyToAdd();
```